# Angular $touched isn't working

Tags: angularjs

When validating form with Angular: 
'ng-show="userFieldForm.email.$invalid && userFieldForm.email.$touched"'
and using Angular //code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js thne it works fine.

But when using //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js.

I did search but didn't find really a solution... I'm sure am missing an info.

Here is a part of the code:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <%--<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>--%>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <%--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-touch.min.js"></script>--%>

        <script src="js/users.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="passUser" ng-controller="usersCntrl">

        <form name="userForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="user in formData.users" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.email.$dirty}">
                <label> {{ user.name }}'s Email </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
                <p class="help-block" ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.email.$dirty">Valid Email Address Required</p>
            </div>
        </form>
      </body>

user.js:

var passUser = angular.module('passUser', [/*'ngAnimate','ui.router,'ngTouch'*/]);

passUser.controller('usersCntrl',['$scope', function($scope){

    var users = [
        {
            name:   'Chris',
            email:  ''
        },
        {
            name:   'Holly',
            email:  ''
        }
    ];

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.users = users;

}]);
```

Any Idea pls?

Thanks
k.min

Comment: maybe because it's not the same version..

Answer (score 4):

$touched was introduced by Angular 1.3

It won't work with 1.2.16

See [here](https://lingohub.com/blog/2014/10/angularjs-migration-guide-1-2-to-1-3/) for changes from 1.2 --> 1.3

Comment: @k.amin Seems like it helped after all. Why post an answer yourself instead of [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) this one?

Comment: @ArtjomB: Cause it didn't work for me with V1.3 See my Answer please. Worked for me with 1.3.9. Can't explain it now as it's an old issue. More than 2 years.